# smooth curves of genus 3 over an algebraic closed field

Tags: genus, ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a way to "easily" compute and describe the Moduli space of smooth curves of genus 3 without stacks and stable curves?

In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry there is a nice excercise (Chapter IV Curves, Excercise 2.2) doing this for g=2. I'm searching for something similar.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Given a genus three curve, consider  the canonical map. It is either two to one onto a plane
conic,  or it is an embedding into the plane as a quartic. 
By counting parameters, you can see that most curves fall into the second (nonhyperelliptic) case. Thus a Zariski open subset of the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_3$  can be described as the space of nonsingular plane quartics mod $PGL_3$. Is this what you were after?